# Exchange Web Services (EWS) C# - Get list of categories

Tags: c#, email, exchangewebservices, categories

I can get a category per item of the mailbox, using item.Categories,

Does anyone know if it is possible to get a unique list of Categories in my mailbox?

I am thinking it may not be possible but if anyone has achieved this before, I would be grateful to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list of categories is stored as a hidden object in the default calendar folder. You can request it with a GetUserConfiguration request with the configuration name "CategoryList" (its an XML property). This was working for me on Exchange 2010 and later.

I'm sorry I can't provide any code sample but I don't know C#.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same requirement found what I was looking for thanks to @frangge suggestion using the following code, including working around a strange bug with some unpredictable leading characters in some responses.

```cs
using Flurl;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

...

        public Categories GetCategories()
        {
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls; 
            string ewsUrl = RootUrl.AppendPathSegment("EWS/Exchange.asmx");

            ExchangeService ewsservice = new Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService
            {
                Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(Username, Password),
                Url = new Uri(ewsUrl)
            };
            UserConfiguration usrConfig = UserConfiguration.Bind(ewsservice,
                                                                     "CategoryList",
                                                                     WellKnownFolderName.Calendar,
                                                                     UserConfigurationProperties.All);
            byte[] xmlData = usrConfig.XmlData;
            //found some nasty leading chars in XmlData which was breaking deserialization
            //it looked something like ï»À<?xml version... o worse an unprintable char
            if (usrConfig.XmlData[0].Equals(239) && usrConfig.XmlData[1].Equals(187) && usrConfig.XmlData[2].Equals(191))
            {
                xmlData = usrConfig.XmlData.Skip(3).ToArray();
            }
            string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(xmlData);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Categories));
            using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                var categories = (Categories)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                return categories;
            }
        }
```

With Category defined as

```cs
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "categories", Namespace = "CategoryList.xsd")]
    public class Categories
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "category")]
        public List<Category> Category { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "default")]
        public string Default { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "lastSavedSession")]
        public int LastSavedSession { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "lastSavedTime")]
        public DateTime LastSavedTime { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xmlns")]
        public string Xmlns { get; set; }
    }
```